# daemonset with nodeSelectors

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

so i naturally run [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and the [k8s-device-plugin](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin) as a `daemonset`. as not all my kubernetes worker nodes have gpus, i use a `nodeSelector` in the daemonset to run just on `node`s that i've labeled with `accelerator=nvidia`.

in another case, i also do the same for [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx): i label a few nodes that i want and run it as a `daemonset`. i then have an external (f5) load balancer that holds the VIP to the relevant DNS records for the ingress endpoints (yeah, i know there's a f5 ingress available - its on the todo list).

i've noticed that many users state that `daemonset`s should only be used for pods that should be running on ALL workers. is there anything inherently bad with my restriction of running `daemonset`s on a subset of nodes?

Answer (score 2):

It's a valid use case. You can restrict the daemonset to run on the nodes that you want by using node selectors.